# How to set which shell does Midnight Commander use?

Tags: shell, mc

As far as I know, Midnight Commander should be able to run different shells within it (the line second to the bottom). My question is, where/how can I configure which shell does mc use? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Midnight Commander uses a shell from the `SHELL` environment variable if it is set, otherwise the shell from `/etc/passwd` entry of the current user, and falls back to a shell installed (in an order) if that fails.

Thus to change the shell in Midnight Commander just set the `SHELL` environment variable.